# Endpoint IP not changed in Prometheus target specified in prometheus.yml

Tags: spring-boot, docker, prometheus

I want to use Prometheus with my spring boot project, I'm new in Prometheus that way i do not know why I get error describe in picture

[image]

My prometheus.yml like below

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'spring_micrometer'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['192.168.43.71:8080/app']
```

I run prometheus  by this command `docker run -d -p 9090:9090 -v <path-to-prometheus.yml>:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus`

I notice my ip not show in Prometheus targets page :

[image]

Normally Endpoint IP must be like `192.168.43.71:8080/app/actuator/prometheus` but I get `http://localhost:9090/metrics` and when I click in it, i get error describe in picture 1

What I do wrong ?!, anyone can help me to resolve this issue and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this `- targets: ['192.168.43.71:8080/app']`. Try the following:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'spring_micrometer'
    metrics_path: '/app/actuator/prometheus/metrics'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['192.168.43.71:8080']
```

Why does your config not work? Take a look at the config docs here: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#host

`targets` is a collection of `host` and `host` must be a "valid string consisting of a hostname or IP followed by an optional port number".